# SQL Query Tree for a given query

Tags: presto

Using the presto SQL parser, is it possible to obtain the query tree for a given query? Our system uses PostgreSQL as the default database. I need the query tree with proper hierarchical structure for implementation of a feature.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but I will describe the different parts of query planning.

The Presto SQL parser simply turn the SQL into a syntax tree.  To work with the query, you will need to analyze and plan the query and then you will have a hierarchical query structure.  At this point, the optimizer reorganizes the query plan for execution.  You can see the final structure by running explain on a query.  For example:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM T
```

Does that help?